# malloc error: incorrect checksum for freed object in struct for reading file

Tags: c, malloc

So I have this function:

```
source_t * source_init(char * argsource)
{
    source_t * temp = (source_t *) malloc(sizeof(source_t *));
    temp->path = realpath(argsource, NULL);
    temp->dir = dirname(temp->path);
    temp->name = basename(temp->path);
    temp->ext = strrchr(temp->name, '.');
    temp->content = read_file(temp->path); // here
    temp->error = error_free();
    return temp;
}
```

It's calling function `read_file()`:

```
char * read_file(char * sourcepath)
{
    char * buffer = NULL;
    long string_size, read_size;
    FILE * file = fopen(sourcepath, "r");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    string_size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);
    buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (string_size + 1) );
    read_size = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), string_size, file);
    buffer[string_size] = '\0';
    if (string_size != read_size)
    {
        free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```

and this error comes up: `malloc: *** error for object 0x7faf08402698: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.` So my current solution is to separately initialise `content` after I have called `source_init()` in the main function. Although that solution works, I want `content` to be initialised in `source_init()`. Also it seems I can't directly call `source_init()` to initialise `content` because the same error comes up so I have to create a buffer to call `source_init()` and initialise `content` to buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably not what you want to do:

```
source_t * temp = (source_t *) malloc(sizeof(source_t *));
```

That allocates space for a *pointer* to a source_t object, nor for a source_t object.

Also, in C you shouldn't cast the return value of malloc. Doing so can hide errors, and make them very hard to find.

Comment: Another reason on top of maintainability to use the form `source_t *temp = malloc( sizeof( *temp ) );`

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999844/1480131)

1. Do not cast `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. That just masks potential errors
2. When possible, do not use `sizeof(<data type>)` when calculating the size. It's easy to make mistakes and makes re-factorization of your code a pain in the ****.

Use this instead

```
source_t *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
```

This has the advantage that `sizeof *temp` returns exactly the correct number of bytes, you don't have to think about the correct type (like when you deal with double/triple pointers) and if you have to change the data type, let's say to `source2_t`, then you only have to change the type of the variable without worrying about pesky `sizeof(<data type>)` that can be overlooked easily.

Answer (score -1):

In source_init() in the malloc() line you have a mistake.

It should be:
`source_t * temp = (source_t *) malloc(sizeof(source_t));`

and not:
`source_t * temp = (source_t *) malloc(sizeof(source_t *));`

Comment: You said "First of all"... is there a second issue that you see?